# Верстка макета приложения

Tags: android, xml

Доброго  времени.
Возможно  вопрос глупый, но все же задам его.
Дали макет  с  разрешением 360х640 пикселей. Все отступы  и  размеры  указанны в пикселях. Как добиться  одинакового  вида на любых  экранах?

Заранее  благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добиться этого используя верстку в пикселях невозможно, т.к. на разных экранах разная плотность пикселей. Используйте относительные величины. Вычисляйте величину отступов и размеров по данному макету и переводите все в процентные соотношения.

Comment: указывая  вес. Но  как  тогда  с  высотой  поступать?

Comment: @alexmx тоже самое для высоты. задаете высоту корневого элемента на весь экран, после чего уже в нем указываете относительные отступы.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала расстреляйте дизайнера, но перед расстрелом пусть отдаст вам оригинал дизайна в фотошопе или CorelDraw - оттуда и возьмите все соотношения. Все равно дизайнеры делают все в векторе в Photoshop/CorelDraw

Comment: голосую за "расстрел")) но скорее по причине столь убитого разрешения. выдавать 360х640 в 2017 году это реально жесть) что касается photoshop - там могут сверстать и в пикселях (что и было скорее всего, раз у автора на руках макет с четким разрешением), и даже есть кадры, которые верстают макеты сайтов/приложений в физических единицах (см, дюймы).

Comment: Встречал дизайнеров, которые верстали UI дизайн с помощью ножниц и клея :)

Comment: ну это уже полная жесть)) здесь даже расстрел не поможет)) хотя в ряде вузов парадигма преподавания дизайна до сих пор не ушла с конца прошлого века.